# Specialize template which includes enableif

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

I want to specialize a `templated` method. It makes use of `std::enable_if` to check a static property of the given type:

```
template <class T, bool fancy= T::IsFancy()>
typename std::enable_if<fancy, void>::type
onlyForFancyGuys(T* component) {
    /*stuff*/
    onlyForFancyGuys(component->parent);
}
```

As I use this for recursive calls, I need a way to determine, when recursion ends. That is, when type `Foo` is used. So I tried this specialization.

```
template<>
typename void onlyForFancyGuys<Foo, true>(Foo* component);
```

and

```
template<>
void onlyForFancyGuys<Foo, true>(Foo* component);
```

But it keeps telling, me that this `template-id` does not match any template declaration. What am I doing wrong here? Is there something specific with `enable_if`?

Important fact: `Foo` does not have the method `IsFancy`.

Edit: I added `IsFancy` to `Foo`, but it does not make any difference.

Edit: I am compiling with MinGW. But I plan to use MSVC, too.

Edit: Adding `IsFancy` to `Foo` together with the accepted answer did the trick.

Comment: I dont see any recursive call here

Comment: What is the purpose of `bool fancy= T::IsFancy()` ?

Comment: It allows me to determine, which collection I should use to store it. One vector for all fancy objects and another container for all non-fancy ones. Later on I can use these for different return types in my get-method, depending on the fancyness.

Comment: What are you compiling with? And btw, this is **not** a [mcve]. It's pseudo code at best.

Comment: Ok thats my fault. I thought pseudo-code is more appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use overload:

```
void onlyForFancyGuys(Foo* component) { /* ... */ }

template <class T, bool fancy = T::IsFancy()>
typename std::enable_if<fancy, void>::type
onlyForFancyGuys(T* component) {
    /*stuff*/
    onlyForFancyGuys(component->parent);
}
```

`template` will be exclude thank to SFINAE (on `T::IsFancy()`)

Comment: This in combination with adding ´IsFancy´ to ´Foo´ worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
template<>
typename void onlyForFancyGuys<Foo, true>(Foo* component);
```

Gid rid tof typename before void.

Comment: I did, but the problem remains. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think at some point in the recursion you are reaching the place where no template can be instantiated.
Try to declare the general template at the top which breaks the recursion first and then do the rest. There is some weird logic that I don't quite understand but I would try this at least to compile. I think that enable_if is not in the right place in your case. Would tipp at some design issues in general.

```
template<typename T>
void onlyForFancyGuys(T* t) {
}
```

and

```
 template<typename T, bool b>
    void onlyForFancyGuys(T* t) {
    }
```

And remove typename before void in the specialization, like somebody said.